# Entityframework two way dependency prequery

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have EF repository, where are tables:

```
public DbSet<Request > Request { get; set; }
public DbSet<Approval> Approvals { get; set; }
```

I can define in my RepositoryContext, how they are queried:

```
IQueryable<Approval> IRepository.Approvals {
    get { return Approvals.Where(a => !a.Flagged); }
}
```

So when I query my approvals, they are now always not flagged:

```
_repository.Approvals.DoWhatEverWithThese() // these are always not flagged
```

On the other hand, I have object that has a List of Approvals attached.

```
public class Request {
     public virtual List<Approval> Approvals { get; set; }
}
```

When I take Approvals directly from Request, they have flagged Approvals inside. How can I preselect the Approvals, that they would not have flagged items inside.

I have tried ExtensionMethods and `[NotMapped]` attribute for domain object, but these give error.

```
public static IEnumerable<Approval> NotFlaggedApprovals(this Request request) {
    return request.Approvals.Where(a => !a.Flagged);
}

[NotMapped]
public List<Approval> NotFlaggedApprovals{
    get { return Approvals == null ? new List<Approval>() : Approvals.Where(a => !a.Flagged).ToList(); }
} 


LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'NotFlaggedApprovals' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

**How can I preselect these**? So I don't always have to write it like this, lots of boilerplate:

```
_repository.Approvals.Where(a => !a.Flagged)
```

Comment: Look [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/filter-collections-automatically-with-entity-framework-code-first). Seems to fit your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try putting the unmapped property into the request object?

```
public partial class Request 
{
    public virtual List<Approval> Approvals { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public List<Approval> NotFlaggedApprovals
    {
        get 
        { 
            return Approvals == null ? new List<Approval>() : Approvals.Where(a => !a.Flagged).ToList(); 
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is in there, and getting error : The specified type member 'NotFlaggedApprovals' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported. The error appears for this line : `var abc = requests.Where(r => r.NotFlaggedApprovals.All(a => a.IsValid)).ToList();`

Comment: Because the calculated property can't be translated by EF into a store expression. You could do an in-memory operation instead by using `requests.AsEnumerable().Where(...)`. Otherwise you'll have to refactor that into something that can be translated.

Comment: Shoe what about extension method, that should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes but you will have to import that extension method wherever you want to use it.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that, but as you can see in my original post, I already have that extension method there and it did not work. The problem is that, extension method will return IEnumerable, it does not get IQueryable.

Comment: Have the extension method return `IQueryable<Approval>`

Comment: The problem is that request.Approvals.Where() does not return IQueryable, it is IEnumerable, and request.Approvals is actually a List.

Comment: What's wrong with changing `Approvals` to an IEnumerable?

Comment: This gives me error: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Approval] NotFlaggedApprovals(Request)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Ah, my bad. That can't be done. The only way is to force evaluation through `AsEnumerable` as I said earlier or evaluate after `ToList` is called. `requests.ToList().Where(r => r.NotFlaggedApprovals.All(a => a.IsValid));`

Comment: Yeah, but I believe, this will slow things down, because toList will pull everything from database and create objects. When I have thousands of rows in DB, its bad.

Comment: You could define a function and pass that into a where clause. Won't save you much but at least it's reusable. `Func<Approval, bool> NotFlaggedApprovals = a => !a.Flagged;` then `requests.Where(r => r.Where(NotFlaggedApprovals).All(...)`